# PNG to SVG batch conversion

Tags: svg, png

Is there a tool to convert 302 PNG images to SVG?
I know how to do it one by one using Inkscape, but I need a tool to convert the 302 image at once.

Comment: Do you want to vectorize them? or put  Png inside a svg, which has not much sense.

Comment: A bit more context would help here. Has Rafael points out, one doesn't really convert PNG files to SVG. One is raster, one is vector.

Comment: Possible duplicate [png to  svg batch conversion](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/37045/batch-trace-jpg-to-svg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may help:
http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/13286/batch-convert-svg-to-png

Put your files on the same folder.
Open your terminal, write

```
cd (your folder path)
```

for example

```
cd /Documents/FilesINeedToConvert
```

Then copy and paste this:

```
svg2png(){ png="${1%.*}.png"; inkscape --export-png="$png" --without-gui "$1" && pngcrush -brute -rem alla -rem text "$png" "$png.new" && mv "$png.new" "$png";}
```

That's for Inkscape, but if you install ImageMagick, you can use these others, here: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php :

this one

```
for i in *.svg; do convert "$i" "${i%.svg}.png"; done
```

OR this

```
find . -name \*.svg -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 -P4 -I{} bash -c 'X={}; convert "$X" "${X%.svg}.png"'
```

Comment: This answer converts SVG to PNG, not PNG to SVG like the question asked... why is it selected as correct?

Comment: This is *distinctly* ***not*** what OP asked for - how did it get upvoted?