# Convert PNG pixel arts to SVG without tracing

Tags: svg, png, pixel-art, file-conversion

For a personal project, I designed some icons as PNG files and would like to export them as SVGs.

I know the next question: I don't want a raster, I need vectors. I found [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/54400/48298) but since it's based on InkScape, I suppose this will involve [tracing](https://inkscape.org/en/doc/tutorials/tracing-pixelart/tutorial-tracing-pixelart.html).

I do not want that. What I am hoping for is more like [pixel2svg](http://florian-berger.de/en/software/pixel2svg/) proposes. Actually, pixel2svg is almost perfect and gives the sort of thing I am looking for.

From the doc:

[image]

[Here](https://github.com/cyChop/crest-generator/blob/master/svg/icons/wolf.svg) is one example from my project.

Only caveat: some of my icons require an intermediary alpha value. pixel2svg appears to be quite binary: either there is a pixel, either it is transparent. Nothing in between. From my project, one of the problematic examples [in PNG](https://github.com/cyChop/crest-generator/blob/master/concepts/glares/linear.png) and [in SVG](https://github.com/cyChop/crest-generator/blob/master/svg/glares/linear.svg).

I tried to look for a contact address to see if this could be changed but I did not find one.

Does anyone know of a solution to generate a pixelated SVGs from (relatively) small (and monochrome, if this helps) PNGs?

## To sum my requirements up

- Vector, no raster
- Pixel by pixel conversion, no tracing
- Take alpha (with intermediate values, not only 0/1) into account
- Optional: Command line would be great, as it would allow for batch conversion

## Edit: enhanced version of pixel2svg

Based on [JohnB's answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/58020/48298), I contacted the original author to submit some changes (typically change RGB to RGBA when alpha is neither 0 nor 255). I have had no answer yet so I created a [Github repo](https://github.com/cyChop/pixel2svg-fork) with the changes to make them available to anyone.

Since, hey, it's Github! Python developers should feel free to fork and make it better (pull requests would help me know Python better). The next big challenge is to group pixels the same colors as the same vectors (doing it in InkScape considerably reduced the SVG size despite InkScape adding much custom information).

Comment: I have to ask: Why do you need it SVG? I assume this is pixel art to begin with?

Comment: That said, I don't know of any way to do this in particular other than the script you showed. Which does look impressive. For the alpha issue, is it for one particular color? Or is it not color-dependent? If the former, you could potentially script Inkscape to handle some global search-and-replace of color. Or, any text editor, for that matter, given SVG is a text file in the first place.

Comment: You could do this in Illustrator with Object -> Create Object Mosaic but it does not preserve transparencies. You will keep the colors of the transparent spots but the pixel itself will no longer be transparent.

Comment: We have a similar question specifically for Illustrator [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/9391/8708). As @Andrew already mentioned, that top voted answer won't work for you, Vincent's answer won't preserve transparency, and well, I'm guessing you don't want to do this by hand as suggested in Scott's answer

Comment: @DA01 Why SVG? To keep it short, because I want to create a web interface to stack images and will need masking and such. Manipulating SVG with JS is not that hard, but binaries... And unfortunately, it is not color-dependent (my PNGs are monochrome, only the alpha changes).

Comment: @JohnB I'd have done by hand if I had no other choice, but I need the transparency preserved (otherwise, pixel2svg would just be perfect).

Comment: @Chop From a technical perspective, what you're asking would require the function to understand what needs transparency and what doesn't, which isn't easy to say the least

Comment: @ZachSaucier I'm sure if it were easy, this question would not be open. ;) I may try to roll up my own solution if none can be found, but reinventing the wheel is never a good idea. (Plus, in this case, it's not easy at all.)

Comment: This is indeed very easy to do. This would be a good exersice for a second C programming course. Anyway,for a really dirty solution, glue a white background and edit the css to be alpha.

Comment: I suspect this wouldn't require too much modification to the pixel2svg source. I'm going to tinker with it tonight, looks like it could be a fun project

Comment: @joojaa and JohnB I suppose our interpretations of the question differ

Comment: @jooja Why add a background when I an looking for partial or total transparency (total is OK, partial becomes alpha = 1 after transformation by pixel2svg)? JohnB I also think it should be possible to edit pixel2svg to make this but Python's not my strong suit. I was thinking of it as a possible quick start.

Comment: @Chop you can use color as a proxy for alpha, then search and replace the result in a text editor to alpha.

Comment: You didn’t mention your software in which you originally designed the icons.

Comment: @NaveedAbbas The original PNG icons were designed with The Gimp. This didn't seem relevant to me for the question as the purpose was to move from "matrix" images to vector ones, no matter the source of the original images.

Comment: thank you :) for the github repo

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[pixel2svg](http://florian-berger.de/en/software/pixel2svg/) has the potential to do this, but it requires some modification of the script.

#### How to do it

You need to modify the `svgdoc.add` call on line 125 of pixel2svg.py to add in opacity attribute. It should look like the following:

```
svgdoc.add(svgdoc.rect(insert = ("{0}px".format(colcount * arguments.squaresize),
                             "{0}px".format(rowcount * arguments.squaresize)),
                       size = ("{0}px".format(arguments.squaresize + arguments.overlap),
                           "{0}px".format(arguments.squaresize + arguments.overlap)),
                       fill = svgwrite.rgb(rgb_tuple[0],
                                       rgb_tuple[1],
                                       rgb_tuple[2]),
                       opacity = rgb_tuple[3]/float(255)))
```

[Here's a diff](https://www.diffchecker.com/bzfcf2ll) of the code change. To show it in action I made [this very tiny image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsEua.png). Here's the SVG produced by the modified pixel2svg (or check it out in action **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/ypp6fjLb/).**):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" baseProfile="full" height="40px" version="1.1" width="440px">
<defs/>
<rect fill="rgb(255,0,255)" height="40px" opacity="0.101960784314" width="40px" x="40px" y="0px"/>
<rect fill="rgb(255,0,255)" height="40px" opacity="0.2" width="40px" x="80px" y="0px"/>
<rect fill="rgb(255,0,255)" height="40px" opacity="0.301960784314" width="40px" x="120px" y="0px"/>
<rect fill="rgb(255,0,255)" height="40px" opacity="0.4" width="40px" x="160px" y="0px"/>
<rect fill="rgb(255,0,255)" height="40px" opacity="0.501960784314" width="40px" x="200px" y="0px"/>
<rect fill="rgb(255,0,255)" height="40px" opacity="0.6" width="40px" x="240px" y="0px"/>
<rect fill="rgb(255,0,255)" height="40px" opacity="0.701960784314" width="40px" x="280px" y="0px"/>
<rect fill="rgb(255,0,255)" height="40px" opacity="0.8" width="40px" x="320px" y="0px"/>
<rect fill="rgb(255,0,255)" height="40px" opacity="0.901960784314" width="40px" x="360px" y="0px"/>
<rect fill="rgb(255,0,255)" height="40px" opacity="1.0" width="40px" x="400px" y="0px"/>
</svg>
```

#### What's going on

pixel2svg uses [PIL](http://pythonware.com/products/pil/) to process through each pixel of the supplied image. It actually already pulls the alpha value of each pixel as an integer [0-255], it just doesn't do much with it:

```
image = PIL.Image.open(positional[0])
print("Converting image to RGBA")
image = image.convert("RGBA")
```

The pixel data is then reconstructed into an SVG using the [svgwrite](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/svgwrite) library. Each pixel is drawn using as the [`svgwrite.shapes.Rect`](http://pythonhosted.org/svgwrite/classes/shapes.html#rect) method which allows you to chain "additional SVG attributes as keyword-arguments". The SVG opacity value expects a float [0.0-1.0], so we just need to normalize the alpha value before setting it as the opacity.

---

Disclaimer: This was my first time ever messing with Python, so feel free to point out any beginner errors I may have made!

Comment: Its perfectly ok stuff a bit ugly on the eye because its all in one line bit fine nonetheless. Personally i dont get why the script needs a dependency to svg write seems overkill and makes distributing the script harder than neccesary.

Comment: I tested, it works. I'll try to have a look at it myself: I think there is no need to add the alpha when it is 100% (makes the file heavier for not much). Otherwise, that's a great result for what looks like a trivial line. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Chop absolutely a good idea to add that functionality to reduce the size! I'm glad it worked for you

Comment: I created a Github repo with an enhanced version of the script. See the edited question for more details. @joojaa, feel free to review and give feedback, I've been planning to learn Python for quite a while but never really had time. Thanks both for the kickstart!

Answer (score 5):

I am a programmer who looked if someone did this before I did (for a pixel art web game). I made a web tool that is, while slow, functional. It shows you the result and the SVG source code: https://codepen.io/tacode/pen/eMaqWG

Answer (score 2):

If you have python and PIL/Pillow, I just wrote this (a trivially simple version of the tool in @JohnB's answer):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
import sys
infile = sys.argv[1]
outfile = sys.argv[2]
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open(infile).convert('RGBA')
data = image.load()
out = open(outfile, "w")
out.write('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>\n')
out.write('<svg id="svg2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="%(x)i" height="%(y)i" viewBox="0 0 %(x)i %(y)i">\n' % {'x':image.size[0], 'y':image.size[1]})
for y in range(image.size[1]):
    for x in range(image.size[0]):
        rgba = data[x, y]
        rgb = '#%02x%02x%02x' % rgba[:3]
        if rgba[3] > 0:
            out.write('<rect width="1" height="1" x="%i" y="%i" fill="%s" fill-opacity="%.2f" />\n' % (x, y, rgb, rgba[3]/255.0))
out.write('</svg>\n')
out.close()
```

Call it with arguments `input.png output.svg` and it should go. I wouldn't try it with anything bigger than a few hundred pixels squared though.

Comment: Nice, clear, and concise. A quick and easy improvement may be to test for horizontal spans of the same RGBA color. I suppose some *marginal* additional gain could be made by testing each new color run for a possible longest horizontal *or* vertical span, but I doubt the added complexity would translate to significantly smaller files.

Answer (score 1):

@Lil Taco's web application is truly fantastic, but it's not very intuitive. I recommend https://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/XbxvNj instead - Similar premise where you can upload a pixelart .png and output a .svg. Website comes with instructions as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not auto trace, the option is **do it by hand**. Make a grid and start drawing boxes.

Your requirements:

- Vector, no raster (OK)
- Pixel by pixel conversion, no tracing (OK) half ok. A vector based file has no pixels.
- Take alpha into account (OK) If you simply do not draw a background.
- Optional: Command line would be great. Any comand line option is a "tracing" Good that is one is optional.

Svg can also include png inside it... but it has not much sense in this case I belive.